# Smooth JavaScript/jQuery scroll to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a horizontal scroll website, but I don't know how to *smoothly* scroll from one element to the other.
I tried the following code:

```
$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
  $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

But it only scrolls to the top, I also tried the jQuery-plugin [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo), but I just can't get it to work, I also tried the jQuery plugin:

```
$('.click').click(function(){
    $.scrollTo( '.last', 800, {easing:'elasout'});
});
```

But also without succes.

Does anyone know a good, easy to understand, sample I can use? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to tell us what isn't "working". You got error messages? What debugging did you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**untested**

```
   $('.click').click(function(){
        $.scrollTo( $('.last'), 800);
    });
```

Comment: If anyone would like to see a demo that uses the jQuery.ScrollTo Plugin he may take a look [at this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722497/scroll-smoothly-to-specific-element-on-page/17742056#17742056)

Answer (score 4):

In case you have to / need to avoid using jQuery here is vanilla JS solution which worked for us nicely:

```js
function scrollToElement(myElement, scrollDuration = 500) {
    const elementExists = document.querySelector(myElement);
    if (elementExists && elementExists.getBoundingClientRect) {
        const rect = elementExists.getBoundingClientRect();
        const elementTop = rect.top + window.scrollY - 200; // a bit of space from top
        var cosParameter = (window.scrollY - elementTop) / 2,
            scrollCount = 0,
            oldTimestamp = performance.now();
        function step(newTimestamp) {
            console.log(scrollCount);
            scrollCount += Math.PI / (scrollDuration / (newTimestamp - oldTimestamp));
            if (scrollCount >= Math.PI) {
                window.scrollTo(0, elementTop);
                return;
            }
            window.scrollTo(0, Math.round(cosParameter + cosParameter * Math.cos(scrollCount)) + elementTop);
            oldTimestamp = newTimestamp;
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        }
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
}
scrollToElement("#yourElement");
```

I hope it helps :)