# Animate the scroll between sections on a single page? (javascript only)

Tags: javascript, scroll, single-page-application, animated

I've found a few posts on here similar to what I'm asking, but they all involve jQuery (I'm looking for a solution that's purely javascript, as simple as possible).

I have a page with a fixed nav on the left, where the different links bring you up or down to different sections on the page. It works fine, but I was trying to find a way to animate the scroll. I managed to come up with some javascript that tells me the offset between the sections:

```
function scroll(e) {
   dest = e.target.getAttribute('href');
```

(for example, this would give me the result of #aboutCon)

```
   destination = dest.replace("#", "");
```

(this changed it to aboutCon which is already defined as a variable containing the "About" section)

```
   var destOffset = window[destination].offsetTop;
   window.scrollTo(0, destOffset); 
}
```

but I have no idea how to take that information and animate it. I've found a few javascript solutions but they're so complicated, whenever I try applying them to my own code, they don't work. I'm hoping there's a simple way to achieve this?

I'm a student and still learning so if you have an answer, an accompanying explanation would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll smoothly to specific element on page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722497/scroll-smoothly-to-specific-element-on-page)

Comment: That was actually incredibly helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("elementID").scrollIntoView();
```

Or cleaning it up a bit...

```
function scrollIntoView(eleID) { 
   var e = document.getElementById(eleID); 
   if (!!e && e.scrollIntoView) {
       e.scrollIntoView();
   }
}
```

Of course replace "elementID" with the ID of the div or element you want to scroll to.

This one is the simplest solution I've found with pure JS.

Comment: This is why we have JQuery. It fixes a lot of the cross browser compatibility. Just use this JQuery CDN and script and it should do what you need plus animate it nicely.<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script> $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 2000);