# Making my JavaScript scroll function smooth

Tags: javascript, html

Hello my current JavaScript is this, to scroll the page to an id tag further down my website page:

```
function scroll(element){   
    var ele = document.getElementById(element);  
    window.scrollTo(ele.offsetLeft,ele.offsetTop);
    window.scrollBy(0, -100);
}
```

How can I make the function scroll smoothly ?

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722497/scroll-smoothly-to-specific-element-on-page) I think it can help you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll smoothly to specific element on page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722497/scroll-smoothly-to-specific-element-on-page)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not Java, this is JavaScript, and those two are different, they are not just two names for one programming language...
For your problem, I would do something like getting the current position of the scroll by using `document.documentElement.scrollTop` (but this one returns 0 on chrome) and the wanted position of the scroll by getting your element's coordinates, and then just move the scroll for a bit of the distance every frame by using `window.scrollBy()` method.
However, I would not suggest this method, because there are other, better solution would be to use [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

Comment: @HassanZia Click the "edited x time ago" link under the question to see the original version, where he uses Java in the title.