# jQuery Animate Method's Duration Property not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I'm trying to apply a smooth scroll animation on my webpage when the navbar links are clicked.

But the **animate** method isn't working and the links won't go to the next section when clicked thus leaving me stuck at the top most section when clicking the links.

I solved this by using the **minified** ver. of **jQuery CDN** instead of the **slim minified**.

Although the links go to their specified sections, the smooth scrolling effect still doesn't apply. They just skip to the next as though the **duration** property in my **jQuery** doesn't exist.

Am I doing something wrong here? I'm using **Bootstrap 4** and I even tried including the **jQuery UI CDN** but it still doesn't work.

Also, I found this on my [console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4XMF.png) could this be the one that's causing the problem?

```js
// Doesn't do the duration
$(".navbar a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<!-- The CDN's that I'm using -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You will find some code using duration here that runs.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722497/scroll-smoothly-to-specific-element-on-page and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31987330/3825777  Take a look at this fiddle for a slightly different approach.  https://jsfiddle.net/s61x7c4e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Changed the code to:

```js
$(".navbar a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    
  document.querySelector(this.hash).scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth" 
  });
});
```

> here's the [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/56164538/13292557), thanks again! @jqueryHtmlCSS

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an issue with your code. Testing here:

```js
$(function() {
  function jumpTo(el, ms) {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(el).offset().top - 2
    }, ms);
  }

  $(".navbar a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jumpTo(this.hash, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.navbar,
.content {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.content {
  height: 1400px;
}

.article {
  width 95%;
  height: 340px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#bar-1 {
  background: #ccd;
}

#bar-2 {
  background: #cdc;
}

#bar-3 {
  background: #dcc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<a id="top"></a>
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#bar-1">Bar 1</a>
  <a href="#bar-2">Bar 2</a>
  <a href="#bar-3">Bar 3</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div id="bar-1" class="article">Bar 1</div>
  <a href="#top">Back to Top</a>
  <div id="bar-2" class="article">Bar 2</div>
  <a href="#top">Back to Top</a>
  <div id="bar-3" class="article">Bar 3</div>
  <a href="#top">Back to Top</a>
</div>
```

Seems smooth to me.

Comment: oh yea wth i dunno why it doesn't work on me maybe it's because I'm using bootstrap? or not i really dunno

Comment: @MoJoex3 any errors in your console? Bootstrap could be related. You didn't mention that in your OP.

Comment: oh yea i forgot to check. 

Here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4XMF.png.

It won't scroll when I'm using the slim minified ver. of the CDN and although it does on the minified ver., it doesn't apply the duration.

Comment: Iv'e included the console output as well on my post I'm really curious as to why this happens.